# VC++ 6.0 - WinDbg stack trace shows a crash point at malloc

Tags: c++, windows, windbg, visual-c++-6

The stack trace in windbg after application crash is as below:

```
ntdll+0x11766
msvcrt!free+0x1ae
msvcrt!free+0x1cc
msvcrt!malloc+0x27
mfc42!Ordinal823+0x2f
```

Please let me know what is this Ordinal means and why free is invoked twice?

Comment: Please show some code or no one can help.

Comment: Ordinal823 (or OrdinalXXX in general) is an anonymous function exported by a DLL apparently: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=392371

Comment: Looking in _%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\MFC\SRC\Intel\MFC42.DEF_, ordinal 823 is `??2@YAPAXI@Z`, which is the decorated name of `operator new`.

Comment: Be careful with your interpretation of the call stack: it _doesn’t_ show that `free` is being called twice (or at all, necessarily); only that the nearest public symbol the debugger can find for the two stack frames above the call to `malloc` is `free`.

Answer (score 1):

When the crash is inside malloc or free, the cause is most likely heap corruption.
The cause for corruption may have happened in code not related to the current stack.
To verify if the heap is corrupted, use

```
!heap –s –v
```

You will need symbols for this, in advance use

```
.symfix
```

You are probably not in free at all, due to lack of symbols the stack is displayed 
with offset to the nearest exports, hence the big offset (free+0x1cc    )
Inspect the stack after the .symfix and enjoy !

To find the root cause for memory corruption different approaches can be used, but if possible full page heap is a good one.